# Required files to run Scrapy in Mac OS x 10.7.5, using Python 2.7.3 IEPD_free (32 bit)

Tags: python, macos, lxml, scrapy

I am testing scrapy for the first time, and after installing it with the command:

```
sudo easy_install -U scrapy
```

everything seems to run ok. However, when I run:

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

I get the following:

```
luismacbookpro:~ luis$ scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
import pkg_resources
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 690, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: lxml
```

Any idea about what's going on? As you can tell, I am not proficient at all with OSX, and I am still trying to move from a windows "mentality" to OSX, so I don't know where to add paths, modify settings, dependencies, etc. Not even sure how to perform a clean uninstall and start all over.

Any feedback is appreciated, even your suggestions to use alternative python libraries that can perform the same functionality of scrapy. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check which python version is installed. You can check this with "python -V".

Comment: Python 2.7.3 IEPD_free 7.3-2 (32 bit). Will edit the Q to add that info. Txs.

Comment: This doesn't look like the default python installation, which would return something like "Python 2.7.2". Have you installed a different python installation?

Comment: I am using Enthought Python Distribution EPD Free, a package that bundles Python with popular scientific libraries for data analysis, mainly SCIPY, NUMPY, IPYTHON, MATPLOTLIB, PANDAS, SYMPY, NOSE, TRAITS, & CHACO. The bundling of libraries allows me the headache of dealing with conflicting libraries and finding the right versions across packages.

Comment: It looks like you messed up the installation, as it tries to access files in the default python installation from OS X.

Comment: Thank you Steve. Do you know how to do a clean uninstall ?

Answer (score 3):

I think this will solve the error message you're seeing:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade lxml
```

This problem can arise on Macs when you use `pip` to install some packages and `easy_install` to install others.

Let us know how you go :)