# Scrapy: Unable to create a project

Tags: python, scrapy, lxml, osx-mountain-lion

I had issues installing scrapy respect to `lxml` but then I found some information on stackoverflow. Based on that information I did a `sudo easy_install lxml` with some error I think scrapy got install:

Reason I came to that judgement is that I repel I could do following:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 28 2013, 07:27:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scrapy import *
>>>
```

But when I try to do the [scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) I get following error:

```
$ scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: lxml
```

Comment: Could you try to `import lxml` - any errors?

Comment: Just tried, no errors

Comment: Ok, thanks, then try: `sudo easy_install --upgrade lxml` and `sudo easy_install --upgrade scrapy`.

Comment: You are simply brilliant -- Thanks may be you should put this as an answer.

Comment: Great, thank you! That wouldn't be fair - the comment was simply based on this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450109/required-files-to-run-scrapy-in-mac-os-x-10-7-5-using-python-2-7-3-iepd-free-3) - @scanny is brilliant :)

Comment: How about you put the answer along with the link for that question, that we we acknowledge the answer from that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450109/required-files-to-run-scrapy-in-mac-os-x-10-7-5-using-python-2-7-3-iepd-free-3):

> This problem can arise on Macs when you use pip to install some
>   packages and easy_install to install others.

Try:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade lxml 
sudo easy_install --upgrade scrapy
```