# scrapy requires python 2.7 but i already have

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, osx-snow-leopard

first of all i'm working on osx 10.6.8

i installed scrapy using the command:

```
sudo easy_install Scrapy
```

and everything seemed working fine. but when i try to create a new project using

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

i only get

```
Scrapy 0.22.2 requires Python 2.7
```

[image: scrapy]

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911345/scrapy-unable-to-create-a-project) solution, but i get the same problem.
how could i fix this?

EDIT: i think i have understood the problem: `easy-install` referrs to an older version of python (2.6) that it is in my system under `/Library/Python/2.6` (probably it was pre-installed), so i installed scrapy for python 2.6! that's why i get the error. but now i don't know how to install scrapy for the right version of python!

Comment: try ```python `which scrapy` startproject tutorial```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved following [this][1] guide and executing again:

```
sudo easy_install scrapy
```

now it works!

Comment: i posted the link to the wrong giude... now i can't find the right one

Answer (score 2):

Execute
`which python`

and

`python --version`

my guess is scrapy is not linking to python2.7 by default.

Comment: i have only python 2.7.3 on my system. i tried to use 'which python' and i get the right path ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python')

Answer (score 0):

Please, open `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py` and insert at line 14:

```
13 if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
14    print(sys.version_info)
15    print("Scrapy %s requires Python 2.7" % __version__)
16    sys.exit(1)
```

then `scrapy startproject tutorial` and show us the output

Comment: under the directory `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/` i can't find `site-packages`.

Comment: `nano $(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())")/scrapy/__init__.py`

Comment: i get this path `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/` but there is only a README file.

Comment: than there should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s‌​crapy.egg`, you can unpack it like `.zip` in `scrapy` directory, remove `.egg` and remove mention of `.egg` in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth`