# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: parsel>=0.9.3

Tags: scrapy, python-3.5

when installing scrapy, I got the following error:

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: parsel>=0.9.3

but I have already installed parsel-1.0.3

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911345/scrapy-unable-to-create-a-project

Comment: Could you also post a more complete console log and add a few notes on your system?